# How i can rename all columns of a tibble in R with the same name using dplyr?

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr

I have a dataframe in R that all the odd number of column have no name and all of them contain dates but in different format (imported from excel file) which looks like this :

```
> data
# A tibble: 557 x 24
   ...1                     x1    ...3                  x2   ...5     x3  ...7                     x4  ...9
   <dttm>                  <dbl> <dttm>                <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dttm>                <dbl> <dbl>
 1 2013-06-13 00:00:00      26.3 2013-02-07 00:00:00    26.6 41312    26.4 2015-06-01 00:00:00    21.4 42156
 2 2013-06-20 00:00:00      26.6 2013-02-08 00:00:00    26.9 41313    26.6 2015-06-02 00:00:00    21.3 42157
 3 2013-10-28 00:00:00      26.2 2013-02-11 00:00:00    26.6 41316    26.4 2015-06-03 00:00:00    21.3 42158
 4 NA                       NA   2013-02-12 00:00:00    26.6 41317    26.4 2015-06-04 00:00:00    21.2 42159
 5 NA                       NA   2013-02-13 00:00:00    26.5 41318    26.3 2015-06-05 00:00:00    21.3 42160
 6 NA                       NA   2013-02-14 00:00:00    26.6 41319    26.4 2015-06-08 00:00:00    21.4 42165
 7 NA                       NA   2013-02-15 00:00:00    26.4 41320    26.2 2015-06-10 00:00:00    21.5 42166
 8 NA                       NA   2013-02-18 00:00:00    26.4 41323    26.2 2015-06-11 00:00:00    21.3 42167
 9 NA                       NA   2013-02-19 00:00:00    26.3 41324    26.1 2015-06-12 00:00:00    21.3 42170
10 NA                       NA   2013-02-20 00:00:00    26.2 41325    26.0 2015-06-15 00:00:00    21.2 42171
```

I want to rename all the columns that have no name with the same name "date" as to have the same format in dates (as.Date()).

I found a way :

```
colnames(data)[seq(1:1000) %% 2 !=0] <- "date"
```

but i want to rename them with the rename() function using dplyr package and finally to format  them with the date issue. How i can do that in R using dplyr ?

Any help ?

Comment: I am afraid `rename` (or `rename_with`) in this case won't allow you to have more than 1 column with the same name. You might consider using a long format to achieve your end.

Comment: @harre how ? i have to pivot longer them all and then rename them? something like :   tidyr::pivot_longer(!starts_with(" "), names_to = "name", values_to = "prices") ? but it doesn't work

Comment: To help you with the date format, we need to know what it looks like in excel, and you'll probably need to import it as characters (not coerce it to double => here you might loose information).

Comment: For the long format you could do something like: `df |> rename_with(~ paste0("d", as.numeric(str_extract(., "\\d+")) - as.numeric(str_extract(., "\\d+")) %/% 2), .cols = starts_with("...")) |> mutate(across(starts_with("d"), lubridate::as_date)) |> pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = c(".value", "observation"), names_sep = 1) |> rename("dates" = d, "prices" = x)`.

Comment: the date formating stil does not work.it reprodusec year of 2085

Comment: Please see comment above.

Comment: how i can import them (the date columns) from excel into R as characters and not dbl ?

Comment: `readxl::read_excel("file", col_types = "text")`; afterwards convert all variables starting with `x` into doubles. Then we can take care of the dates.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247331/discussion-between-homer-jay-simpson-and-harre).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want something like this? (Names must be unique)

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rename_with(~stringr::str_replace(.,"...","date" ), .cols = contains("...")) %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("date"), ~lubridate::as_date(.)))
```

Output:

```
        date1   x1      date3   x2      date5   x3      date7   x4      date9
1  2013-06-13 26.3 2013-02-07 26.6 2083-02-09 26.4 2015-06-01 21.4 2085-06-02
2  2013-06-20 26.6 2013-02-08 26.9 2083-02-10 26.6 2015-06-02 21.3 2085-06-03
3  2013-10-28 26.2 2013-02-11 26.6 2083-02-13 26.4 2015-06-03 21.3 2085-06-04
4        <NA>   NA 2013-02-12 26.6 2083-02-14 26.4 2015-06-04 21.2 2085-06-05
5        <NA>   NA 2013-02-13 26.5 2083-02-15 26.3 2015-06-05 21.3 2085-06-06
6        <NA>   NA 2013-02-14 26.6 2083-02-16 26.4 2015-06-08 21.4 2085-06-11
7        <NA>   NA 2013-02-15 26.4 2083-02-17 26.2 2015-06-10 21.5 2085-06-12
8        <NA>   NA 2013-02-18 26.4 2083-02-20 26.2 2015-06-11 21.3 2085-06-13
9        <NA>   NA 2013-02-19 26.3 2083-02-21 26.1 2015-06-12 21.3 2085-06-16
10       <NA>   NA 2013-02-20 26.2 2083-02-22 26.0 2015-06-15 21.2 2085-06-17
```

Input:

```
df <- read.table(text = "...1                     x1    ...3                  x2   ...5     x3  ...7                     x4  ...9
 2013-06-13      26.3 2013-02-07     26.6 41312    26.4 2015-06-01     21.4 42156
 2013-06-20      26.6 2013-02-08     26.9 41313    26.6 2015-06-02     21.3 42157
 2013-10-28      26.2 2013-02-11     26.6 41316    26.4 2015-06-03     21.3 42158
 NA                       NA   2013-02-12     26.6 41317    26.4 2015-06-04     21.2 42159
 NA                       NA   2013-02-13     26.5 41318    26.3 2015-06-05     21.3 42160
 NA                       NA   2013-02-14     26.6 41319    26.4 2015-06-08     21.4 42165
 NA                       NA   2013-02-15     26.4 41320    26.2 2015-06-10     21.5 42166
 NA                       NA   2013-02-18     26.4 41323    26.2 2015-06-11     21.3 42167
 NA                       NA   2013-02-19     26.3 41324    26.1 2015-06-12     21.3 42170
 NA                       NA   2013-02-20     26.2 41325    26.0 2015-06-15     21.2 42171
", h = T)
```

Comment: it adds a number in each column date and also the format does not work.it reproduces year 2085.I want all the date columns to have the same name "date".

Comment: Do you want all date columns to be called "date"? That is not possible, they have to be unique. Concerning the date issues, I used a slightly different date input format, but the genereal idea using `mutate` and `across` should work.

Comment: the date formating does not work.I will use my solution though for the renaming issue

Comment: any help with the date formating issue i would appreciate it

Comment: use lubridate's `as_datetime()` to obtain columns with dttm format